# Is there a good way to do TDD in Siebel?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, siebel

I am looking for a way/solution to implement TDD in Siebel development.

I come from web development world and i used a lot unit testing, integration platform and other XP things.

Today i am working on Siebel CRM development for a new job in business in and i am shocked to see that there is no test automation solution in place.

I am currently searching for some documentations, feedbacks, or all other interesting things regarding TDD in Siebel development environemnt.

I could develop some tools myself but i don't want to reinvent the wheel.

If someone have more informations, interesting articles, interesting way to do this it could be very usefull for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is really several questions in one. TDD is a way of working, but I think you are already wel versed in what this entails. It can be applied to any kind of technology. From that stance I feel comfortable saying that it's possible with Siebel as well.

As for the tooling to be used, it very much depends on the version of Siebel you are on (HI/Open UI), the skills of your developers, the way of working at your project (Agile/Waterfall), the test (automation) tooling used and the general level of automation at the project/program.

To me it sounds more like a way-of-working transformation then the implementation of a test approach.